# Really flickery graphics even with BufferedImage

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I'm using a `BufferedImage` for smooth graphics (i.e. with no flicker). However, the square that is drawn in the middle is extremely flickery, and is actually invisible sometimes. I don't know what is wrong, this method has worked fine for my other games.

Here is my code (Square is type defined by me):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class DodgeArrows extends Applet implements KeyListener,Runnable{
    BufferedImage backbuffer;
    Thread gameloop;
    Square player;
    Random r = new Random();
    Graphics2D g2d;
    AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
    public void init()
    {
        backbuffer = new BufferedImage(640,480,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = backbuffer.createGraphics();
        player = new Square();
        player.setX(320);
        player.setY(480);
    }
    public void start()
    {
        gameloop = new Thread(this);
        gameloop.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        while(t==gameloop)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        gameloop = null;
    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height);
        g2d.setColor(player.getColor());
        g2d.fill(player.getShape());
        paint(g);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        //irrelevant keylistener code 
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(backbuffer,0,0,this);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I like applets. I am an enthusiast, not a pro.

Comment: Well there you go.. I figured there had to be *someone* in the world that enjoys the pain.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson pain? I find little pain in coding applets

Comment: The pain mostly comes in deploying them, if you pay any attention to the users who complain about how it does not work in this or that version of their favorite browser.

Comment: @AndrewThompson that is true, however i make them just for fun in appletviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line `g2d = (Graphics2D)g;` from your update(...) method and all your problems will go away.

You already created a backbuffer in the line `g2d = backbuffer.createGraphics();`. When you assign `g` to `g2d` you are making them both refer to the same Graphics object and are throwing away your buffer. You are back to drawing directly to the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that! Edited above.